# Better usage of `make_pass_decorator` in Python Click

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, python-click

I am looking for some advice to **avoid having to instantiate a class twice**; this is more of a design pattern question. I am creating an application using the [Python Click](http://click.pocoo.org/) library.

I have a `Settings` class that first loads all initial default settings into a dictionary (hard-coded into the application), then loads all settings overrides (if specified) from a TOML file on the user's computer into a dictionary, and then finally merges the two and makes them available as attributes of the class instance (`settings.<something>`).

For most of these settings, I ***also*** want to be able to specify a command-line flag. The priority then becomes:

1. Command-line flag. If not specified, then fallback to...
2. User setting in TOML file. If not specified, then finally fallback to...
3. Application default

In order to achieve this result, I am finding that, when using Click's decorators, I have to do something like this:

```
import click
from myapp import Settings

settings = Settings()
pass_settings = click.make_pass_decorator(Settings, ensure=True)

@click.command()
@click.help_option('-h', '--help')
@click.option(
    '-s', '--disk-size',
    default=settings.instance_disk_size,
    help="Disk size",
    show_default=True,
    type=int
)
@click.option(
    '-t', '--disk-type',
    default=settings.instance_disk_type,
    help="Disk type",
    show_default=True,
    type=click.Choice(['pd-standard', 'pd-ssd'])
)
@pass_settings
def create(settings, disk_size, disk_type):
    print(disk_size)
    print(disk_type)
```

#### Why twice?

- The `settings = Settings()` line is needed to provide the `@click.option` decorators with the `default` value. The `default` value could either come from the user override TOML file (if present), or from the application default.
- The [click.make_pass_decorator](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.make_pass_decorator) seems to be the recommended way for interleaved commands; it's even mentioned [in their documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/6/complex/#interleaved-commands). Inside of the function, in addition to the CLI parameters passed, I also sometimes needs to reference other attributes in the `Settings` class.

My question is, *which is better?* Is there a way to use the `pass_settings` decorator in the other `click.option` decorators? Or should I ditch using `click.make_pass_decorator` entirely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to approach the problem of not wanting to instantiate `Settings` twice, is to inherit from `click.Option`, and insert the settings instance into
the context directly like:

#### Custom Class:

```
def build_settings_option_class(settings_instance):

    def set_default(default_name):

        class Cls(click.Option):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                kwargs['default'] = getattr(settings_instance, default_name)
                super(Cls, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            def handle_parse_result(self, ctx, opts, args):
                obj = ctx.find_object(type(settings_instance))
                if obj is None:
                    ctx.obj = settings_instance

                return super(Cls, self).handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)

        return Cls

    return set_default
```

#### Using Custom Class:

To use the custom class, pass the `cls` parameter to `@click.option()` decorator like:

```
# instantiate settings
settings = Settings()

# get the setting option builder
settings_option_cls = build_settings_option_class(settings)

# decorate with an option with an appropraie option name
@click.option("--an_option", cls=settings_option_cls('default_setting_name'))
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.option()` decorator usually instantiates a
`click.Option` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the cls parameter. So it is a relatively
easy matter to inherit from `click.Option` in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

In this case we use a couple of closures to capture the Settings instance and parameter name.  In the returned
class we over ride `click.Option.handle_parse_result()` to allow us to insert the setting object into the context.
This allows the `pass_settings` decorator to find the settings in the context, and thus it will not need to create a new instance.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

class Settings(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_disk_size = 100
        self.instance_disk_type = 'pd-ssd'


settings = Settings()
settings_option_cls = build_settings_option_class(settings)
pass_settings = click.make_pass_decorator(Settings)


@click.command()
@click.help_option('-h', '--help')
@click.option(
    '-s', '--disk-size',
    cls=settings_option_cls('instance_disk_size'),
    help="Disk size",
    show_default=True,
    type=int
)
@click.option(
    '-t', '--disk-type',
    cls=settings_option_cls('instance_disk_type'),
    help="Disk type",
    show_default=True,
    type=click.Choice(['pd-standard', 'pd-ssd'])
)
@pass_settings
def create(settings, disk_size, disk_type):
    print(disk_size)
    print(disk_type)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '-t pd-standard -s 200',
        '-t pd-standard',
        '-s 200',
        '',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            create(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Test Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 23:14:31) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
-----------
> -t pd-standard -s 200
200
pd-standard
-----------
> -t pd-standard
100
pd-standard
-----------
> -s 200
200
pd-ssd
-----------
> 
100
pd-ssd
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -h, --help                      Show this message and exit.
  -s, --disk-size INTEGER         Disk size  [default: 100]
  -t, --disk-type [pd-standard|pd-ssd]
                                  Disk type  [default: pd-ssd]
```

Comment: Stephen, such a high quality answer, and exactly what I was looking for! I'm getting better at Python, but questions like I had are often troublesome for a beginner/intermediate. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ScottCrooks, thanks for the kind words. I would reciprocate by saying your question was also very high quality.  I have answered a [fair number of Click Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-click/topusers) over the last year, and most are not nearly as well formulated as this one.  A great question is often much easier to answer...  Cheers and good luck on your Python journey.

Answer (score 1):

## Differing opinion

Instead of modifying the click invocation and using dynamic class construction, expose the default settings as a class attribute for the Settings class. IE:

```py
@click.option(
    '-t', '--disk-type',
    default=settings.instance_disk_type,
    help="Disk type",
    show_default=True,
    type=click.Choice(['pd-standard', 'pd-ssd'])
)
```

becomes

```py
@click.option(
    '-t', '--disk-type',
    default=Settings.defaults.instance_disk_type,
    help="Disk type",
    show_default=True,
    type=click.Choice(['pd-standard', 'pd-ssd'])
)
```

This is likely cleaner and makes the semantics (meaning) of your code much clearer than using a class constructor s in the accepted answer.

In fact, the `Settings.defaults` could well be an instance of `Settings`. It doesn't mater that you're instantiating twice, as this isn't really the issue here, rather that your client/consumer code for the Settings object has to perform the instantiation. If that's done in the `Settings` class, it remains a clean API and doesn't require the caller to instantiate twice.